# google apps script DateItem get dropdown box

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

So using Google Apps Scripts with a Form, I'm able to get all the items and iterate through them using the following:

```
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
var items = form.getItems();
  var item;

  for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
  {
    item = items[i];

    if(item.getType() == FormApp.ItemType.DATE)
    {
      item = item.asDateItem();
      item.dropdown.month; // I need a method like this
    }
    Logger.log("ItemTitle: %s ItemType: %s",items[i].getTitle(), items[i].getType()) ;
  }
```

I can even get the DateItem that I want.
My issue is that I cannot get the dropdown boxes from the DateItem. Does anyone know how to get the dropdown boxes from the DateItem? (Like: item.dropdown.month or item.dropdown.day, etc).

Answer (score 0):

**FormApp** describes the questions you're asking, not the answers received from people who filled the form out. The type of question is "when were you born?" - nobody answered it yet - there's no date available.

When the form submits, its results go into a spreadsheet. Write a script that parses the spreadsheet's content.

Comment: This is very true. I've edited my question. What I need is to get the underlying dropdown boxes that are for the month, year, etc. If I can get that object, I can then use the onchange event to see the value that the user has entered and act accordingly.

Comment: I see. Now that, I don't think you can do... :(

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of dynamic form behavior (a form that responds live as users fill it out), your best bet is to build and HTML user interface using the HTMLService: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

This is significantly more complicated than working with the FormApp Class, but is much more powerful, and eventually allows you to deploy your code as a web app, or publish as an add-on for Sheets, Docs, or Forms.